# What is the Springdoc equivalent of the Swagger 2 Springfox useDefaultResponseMessages() method?

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, swagger-3.0

We are moving away from Springfox to Springdoc and would like to know if Springdoc has a useDefaultResponseMessages() equivalent?

Have seen some solutions that require some coding but what I would like to know if there is something that can be implemented as simply as the useDefaultResponseMessages()

When creating a default docket in springfox it is very simply added like so.

```
defaultDocket
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(true)
            .select()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use OpenApiCustomiser, to add global responses for your APIs.

```java
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser customerGlobalHeaderOpenApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi -> {
        openApi.getPaths().values().forEach(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().forEach(operation -> {
            ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();
            ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse().description("Custom Error")
                    .content(new Content()
                                .addMediaType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, new MediaType()));
            apiResponses.addApiResponse("400", apiResponse);
        }));
    };
}
```